# Issue connecting Bull Queue to redis through docker containers

Tags: node.js, docker, redis, node-redis

i have seen this question asked around a couple times, but never found a proper answer that works for me, so i will give it a go.

I have sat up a worker service in its own docker container which uses Bull Queue.
Then i have redis in a seperate container. All worked fine when redis was in a container and the worker was running locally, but now the worker just prints Error connecting to Redis: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1278:16) {
errno: -111,
code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
syscall: 'connect',
address: '127.0.0.1',
port: 6379
}

Which i find kind of strange, since i am referring to the container name when i set up Bull. In fact no matter  what i change the host to in the setup, it prints the same error. Unless i run the worker locally, then it prints whichever host i input.
I have also tried changing the "connectionName" field without any changes.

Docker compose:

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    restart: always
    container_name: my_cache
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'
    command: redis-server --save 20 1 --loglevel warning --requirepass pirate
    volumes:
      - redis-data:/data
  worker:
    image: worker
    build: ../worker
    environment:
      - REDIS_HOST=local:redis:6379
    ports:
      - "6000:6000"
    links:
      - redis
volumes:
  redis-data:
    driver: local
```

queue.ts

```
import Bull from "bull";

export const gameEventQueue = new Bull("game-event", {
    redis: {
        host: 'redis',
        password: "pirate"
    }
});
```

Bull versions
"bull": "^4.12.2",
"bull-board": "^2.1.3",

i also tried to set ENV in docker compose like this

```
 worker:
    image: worker
    build: ../worker
    environment:
      - REDIS_HOST=local:redis:6379
```

And connect like this,

```
import Bull from "bull";

export const gameEventQueue = new Bull("game-event", {
    redis: {
        host: process.env.REDIS_HOST,
        password: "pirate"
    }
});
```

But still no Joy. I appreciate all help

Comment: After trying the test suggested by @datawookie, i have come to the conclusion that the docker network in itself is fine, the bash scrip in its own container seems to reach the redis service with successful pings. I just cant seem to figure out why bull keeps reverting to localhost when spun up in a docker image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The network name for the Redis container will simply be `redis`. Here's a setup to demonstrate.

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    restart: always
    container_name: cache
    ports:
     - '6379:6379'
    command: redis-server --save 20 1 --loglevel warning --requirepass pirate
    logging:
      driver: "none"
  worker:
    image: worker
    container_name: worker
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      - REDIS_HOST=redis
      - REDIS_PORT=6379
      - REDIS_PASSWORD=pirate
```

I'm suppressing output from the `redis` service just to keep things clean. There are three environment variables being passed to the `worker` service, with the network host and port for the Redis container and the password.

Now a simple Docker image for the worker. The `iputils-ping` package is just required so that we can run `ping` in the worker.

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04

RUN apt update -q && apt install -q -y redis-tools iputils-ping

COPY worker.sh .

CMD ["bash", "worker.sh"]
```

Finally a worker script, which is just a simple BASH script that demonstrates connecting to the Redis container. This is what it does:

1. Uses `ping` to echo packets off the Redis container.
2. Uses `redis-cli` to send the `PING` command to the Redis server.

`worker.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Worker starting... done!"

echo "Redis at $REDIS_HOST:$REDIS_PORT."

ping -c 5 $REDIS_HOST

echo "Sending PING to Redis..."

redis-cli -h $REDIS_HOST -p $REDIS_PORT -a $REDIS_PASSWORD PING

echo "Done!"

echo "Worker stopping... done!"
```

And here's what that looks like:

[image]

If you look carefully you'll see:

1. Five network pings (immediately after the log message that begins with `PING redis`. This establishes that the worker container can see the Redis container.
2. A successful Redis `PING` command, to which the server responds with a `PONG` (which is also visible in the logs).

Answer (score 0):

My issue was currently that the dockerfile did not run the build steps correctly, so it kept deploying the outdated host to my container, which is why it worked locally